# SharePoint Security: Claim Security Lifetime not working for IP-STS

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, saml, claims

The lifetime on my webapplication is not working in SharePoint 2010 with a custom Claim Authentication Provider.

When I login after 15 min (the time between the "NotBefore" and the "NotOnIrAfter") my session will be close and I need to logon again. In this 15 min I'm just browsing in my webapplication so the session will not timeout.

For Froms Authentication the lifetime configuration in SPSecutiryTokenServiceConfig works with the default value of 00:10:00 minutes. Also in this session I'm browsing in my webapplication and only when the session is idle for the lifetime of 10 min, this will close my session.

Now I'm trying to get the lifetime also working for claims authentication, but with no success. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thnx